Error CS1061 '...Page...' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent'
Get Compilation error
"Error CS1061: '...Page...' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent' and no accessible extension method 'InitializeComponent' accepting a first argument of type '...Page ...' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
The line this.InitializeComponent(); is marked with a red line.
See my own answer.

If you have copied a page (.XAML) into your project with 'Add'.'Existing Item...', the property 'Build Action' for the .XAML file is probably set to 'None', it should be 'Page'.

FYI, build actions for XAML files are handled automatically now for WinUI 3 / WASDK. Their entries can just be deleted from project files when they are erroneously added by Visual Studio. InitializeComponent errors typically go away after a project is built.
